# Why post requests on other files than server.js doesn't work in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a beginner in node.js. I am meeting the following problem:
When I make a post request on a function which is in an external file (another file than server.js) it doesn't work (on postman it is loading for a long time, and I have a "could not get any response answer").
For example, when I copy my function on server.js it works. Here is my server.js file and my actionVideo.js file.
Server.js:

```
let express = require('express')
let app = express()
let bodyParser = require('body-parser')
let session = require('express-session')
let cors = require('cors')
let upload = require('express-fileupload')

app.use(upload())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })) // Middleware permettant de recuperer facilement les attributs de requête
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.set('trust proxy', 1)
app.use(session({
  secret: 'yolo',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: false, httpOnly: false, maxAge: 3600000 }
}))
app.use(cors())
let conn = require('./tools/DB').conn
let id_user = 7;

app.post('/t1', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body); 
  let id_user_subscribe = req.body.id;

  let sqlRegister = 'INSERT INTO lt_abonnement( id_user, id_userChaine) VALUES ( ?, ?)';

  conn.query(
    sqlRegister,
    [id_user, id_user_subscribe],
    function (error, results, fields) {
      if(error) {
        res.json({success : false })
        console.log(error);
      }
      else res.json({success : true})
    })
  }
)


console.log(__dirname + '/user/searchTools')
 app.get('/', express.static('../your-leaf/dist/')) // Sur la racine, rediriger vers la page web
 app.use('/dist', express.static('../your-leaf/dist/')) // Sur la racine, rediriger vers la page web
 app.use('/register', express.static('../your-leaf/dist/')) // Sur la racine, rediriger vers la page web
 app.use('/temp', express.static('./temp')) // Sur la racine, rediriger vers la page web
 app.use('/uploadVideo', express.static('../your-leaf/dist/')) // Sur la racine, rediriger vers la page web

var router = express.Router()

app.use('/user', router) // utilisation du module user
require(__dirname + '/user/user')(router)

app.use('/searchTools', router) // utilisation du module searchTools
require(__dirname + '/user/searchTools')(router)

app.use('/infoUser', router) // utilisation du module infoUser
require(__dirname + '/user/infoUser')(router)

app.use('/actionVideo', router) // utilisation du module actionVideo
require(__dirname + '/video/actionVideo')(router)

app.use('/infoVideo', router) // utilisation du module infoVideo
require(__dirname + '/video/infoVideo')(router)

app.use('/manageVideo', router) // utilisation du module manageVideo
require(__dirname + '/video/manageVideo')(router)


app.listen(4200)
```

And my actionVideo.js which is in the video folder:

```
let conn = require('../tools/DB').conn
let id_user = 7;


function addSubscription(req, res) { // idUserSubscription
  console.log("fgrgtre"); 
  let id_user_subscribe = req.body.id;

  let sqlRegister = 'INSERT INTO lt_abonnement( id_user, id_userChaine) VALUES ( ?, ?)';

  conn.query(
    sqlRegister,
    [id_user, id_user_subscribe],
    function (error, results, fields) {
      if(error) {
        res.json({success : false })
        console.log(error);
      }
      else res.json({success : true})
    })
    res.json({rr: "re"})
  }

function addSubscription(req, res) { // idUserSubscription

}

function removeSubscription(req, res) { // idUserSubscription

}

function like(req, res) { // isLike, idVideo

}

function addComment(req, res) { // idVideo, text

}

function updateComment(req, res) { // idVideo, idComment, text

}

function removeComment(req, res) { // idVideo, idComment

}

function addVue(req, res) { // idVideo

}

module.exports = function (app) {

  app.post('/addSubscription', addSubscription)
  app.post('/removeSubscription', removeSubscription)
  app.post('/like', like)
  app.post('/addComment', addComment)
  app.post('/updateComment', updateComment)
  app.post('/removeComment', removeComment)
  app.post('/addVue', addVue)
}
console.log("fjoe");
```

If I request http://localhost:4200/t1 it works but if I request http://localhost:4200/actionVideo/addSubscription it doesn't work.
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass the same router to each module then every route handler you register in the modules (`/addSubscription`) will be registered for every top level route. For example `/user/addSubscription` and `/searchTools/addSubscription`. This is probably not what you want.

I would export from each module a new router and register that on the top level router. Doing so you can be sure that nothing will interfere with routes defined in `actionVideo.js`.

So in `actionVideo.js`:

```js
const router = express.Router();

app.post('/addSubscription', addSubscription);
// ... and the other routes

module.exports = router;
```

In `server.js`:

```js
const actionVideoRouter = require('./video/actionVideo');

app.use('/actionVideo', actionVideoRouter);
```

You can also see an example in the express docs: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router